# Using add_action hook of GravityForms add-on stickylist

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin, gravityforms

GravityForms has a simple action hook that can be used after submission

> add_action( 'gform_after_submission', 'my_function', 10, 2 );

my_function is any user-defined function where the call reaches if the action hook is found in functions.php

StickyList, an add-on built on GravityForms also provides an action hook that can be used after the form is submitted. It is here below

> add_action("gform_after_submission", array($this, "post_edit_entry"),
>   10, 2);

My question is, how does one use the *my_function* to the StickyList action hook which hasn't specified/documented how to use this action hook. I don't know what the array is doing as a second argument and how to get the call to reach my user defined function once this action_hook is found in functions.php.

Comment: just look at documentation before asking some question. there isn't any errors, and you don't need help. just want to know - use search engine/documentation of target: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/

Comment: `array` used because `add_action` calling class method `post_edit_entry`.

Comment: The stickyList add_action hook after editing entry I found that worked was the following: add_action('stickylist_entry_edited','my_function', 10, 2 );

@Sam

Comment: @Samvel, I now uderstand what you are saying. It is adding a hook to the GravityForms Form Submission saying - go to _post_edit_entry()_ after submitting form. 

What I don't understand is: post_edit_entry() has two parameters - $entry, $form. 

_public function post_edit_entry($entry, $form)_

But add_action only sends $this inside the array

How does post_edit_entry receive $entry and $form objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stickyList add_action hook after editing entry I found that worked was the following. Thanks Samvel for your help.

```
add_action('stickylist_entry_edited','my_function', 10, 2 );
```